# How to setup custom settings.gradle at Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I need to build a project in Android Studio using second settings gradle file (for sample settings-lite.gradle). How to do that? Andriod Studio version is 2021.2.1.

PS: I don't need to build the project by CLI.